# Help with Zotac zbox nano ad10 mini pc ?

Tags: sound, drivers

I have a Zotac Zbox nano ad10. I have it connected to a Samsung Syncmaster t220hd monitor via a HDMI cable for audio and sound, everything else works apart from sound.

I have tired Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10, 12.04 beta 1, LinuxMint 12, Lubuntu 11.10, and other Linux distributions all with the same issue.

On Zotac's website I don't see any Linux drivers to help the issue ?

Please help, thank you in advance to everyone.

I have also tried to install windows 7 on this same computer and the audio works fine. it just does not want to work with Linux.

Comment: Hi, Razor. I understand the AD10 has an audio output jack, as well as the HDMI port. Is the issue you have strictly with HDMI audio, or do you also have no sound from that jack?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Linux Mint 12 KDE (based on Ubuntu 11.10). Full install on Zotac ZBOX Nano 10. Had zero sound from HDMI. Not sure which of these things fixed it, but it is working now.

1. Did ALL updates. No HDMI sound at this point.
2. Did search for proprietary drivers thru Applications/System//Extra Drivers.
3. Installed the first AMD Driver in the list. (2nd one did not work). Rebooted. Still no sound.
4. Unplugged HDMI from the ZBOX and replugged. Still no sound.
5. Opened Audio Mixer by clicking Speaker Icon(Volume control) in tray. Saw notification that Mint 12 thought there were several files (AMD DRIVERS) that it could ignore and asked for confirmation. I chose "NO".
6. In the Audio Mixer I selected "Settings", then in the Sound and Video Configuration Window I selected Device Preferences/Audio Playback/Music. In Rt. Side pane highlighted Internal Audio Digital Stereo(HDMI)
7. Pressed "Test" button- Viola! Sound! YAY!
8. With Internal Audio Digital Stereo(HDMI) still highlighted, pressed the "Prefer" button. This moved HDMI to the Top of the Device Preference list. Clicked on "Apply".
9. Opened up AMAROK and started listening to killer digital music on the Cool Streams "Darkerradio" Stream. Sweetness!

Answer (score 1):

Probably going to be something for a  developer, might contact Zotac

```
ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd.
19/F., Shatin Galleria, 18-24 Shan Mei Street,
Fo Tan, Shatin, N.T. Hong Kong
Tel: (852) 2799 8011
Fax: (852) 2664 2044, (852) 2799 2116
Web Site: www.zotac.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I contacted zotac and apparently they don't support anything other than Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7. Great help they were.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to install the AMD/ATI driver. Then open a terminal window and type `alsamixer`.

Use <kbd>F6</kbd> to select HDMI sound card, select S/PDIF, and press <kbd>M</kbd> (that will change the `00` into an `MM`).

Enjoy your HDMI sound.

Answer (score 0):

I used this how to, to set up my zotac ad10:
http://youresuchageek.blogspot.com/2012/06/xbmc-install-and-config-howto-for-linux.html

I got everything except the bluetooth working